# Drop down menu in Canvas using Kinetic or Easel.js

Tags: select, canvas, kineticjs, easeljs

I need to create a totally self contained web application that allows a user to select different options in select drop downs, as well as input text.

My plan was to create the entire app within Canvas. However, being a novice at Canvas coding, not sure what is possible.

Can any canvas experts tell me if creating drop down select menus, text inputs, and submit buttons are all possible if all contained within a canvas element?

Answer (score 2):

What ?

Sound like the worst idea ever. You want to create a graphical tool kit in the canvas which is a lot of work and you have are in the DOM which is one of the the best graphical tool kit available.

No mater how complex your widgets are it will always be easier to just use the DOM or even SVG if you have some very complex widgets needs. But the canvas is for bitmap drawing.

Just use Absolute positioning to put DOM elements on top of you canvas.